# Wie trennt man eine lange E-Mail-Adresse richtig?

Tags: hyphenation

Gibt es eine gültige/bindende Regel für die Trennung (bei einem Zeilenumbruch) von E-Mail-Adressen? Kommt ja immer mal vor, dass eine E-Mail-Adresse lang wird. In meinem konkreten Fall lautet die Adresse

> vorname.nachname1-nachname2@firmenteil1-firmenteil2.de

Das passt in keinen Spaltensatz und auch eine Visitenkarte hat ihre Grenzen. Habt Ihr Erfahrung mit sowas?

Comment: Ich habe dazu lediglich in einem Forum ein paar Antworten gefunden, allerdings wird dort auch nicht von verbindlichen Regeln gesprochen und es soll hier nur als Zusatzinformation dienen: http://www.typografie.info/3/topic/28146-e-mail-adresse-trennung/

Comment: EIne e-Mail-Adresse umzubrechen ist m.A. nach ein *Ver*brechen. Die Möglichkieten, den Umbruch zu mißdeuten, sind einfach zu mannigfaltig.

Comment: Langfristig würde ich auf jeden Fall zu einer kürzeren E-Mail-Adresse raten. Wenn diese gedruckt wird, heißt das ja auch, das erwartet wird, das irgendjemand sie abtippt, und der wird bei so einem Monster alles andere als begeistert sein, Trennung hin oder her.

Comment: Solche Emailadressmonster tippt niemand ab. Weglassen. Ändern lassen.

Comment: Bei sehr langen E-Mail-Adressen auf Visitenkarten würde ich empfehlen, die Adressse spiralförmig um die Karte laufen zu lassen.

Answer (score 8):

Das Problem besteht darin, dass bei einer Trennung der E-Mail-Adresse nicht klar ist, ob der Bindestrich am Zeilenende einen Trennstrich darstellen soll, oder ob er integraler Bestandteil der E-Mail-Adresse ist.

#### 1. Möglichkeit

Man formuliert den Satz so um, dass die E-Mail-Adresse vollständig in die Zeile passt. In den meisten Fällen sollte das zu schaffen sein.

#### 2. Möglichkeit

Man setzt die E-Mail-Adresse in eine eigene Zeile, ähnlich wie in mathematischen Texten, wo Formeln häufig in eigene Zeilen gesetzt werden.

#### 3. Möglichkeit

Man setzt sich über die Regeln der Getrenntschreibung hinweg und trennt die E-Mail-Adresse ohne zusätzlichen Trennstrich, falls möglich vor oder hinter dem @-Zeichen, aber nicht vor oder hinter einem Punkt (der könnte mit dem Satzendezeichen verwechselt werden).

---

Edit:

#### 3.1. Möglichkeit (Zusatz)

Durch einen Kommentar von [user unknown](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/266/user-unknown) kam ich darauf, dass man die E-Mail-Adresse natürlich auch durch Formatierung vom Text abheben kann – zum Beispiel durch eine andere Farbe oder, was ich bevorzugen würde, durch Kursivierung. Das ist zwar keine eigenständige Möglichkeit zur Trennung, hilft aber beim Lesen. Zudem kann man dann auch an einem Punkt trennen.

> Sie können mich entweder unter der E-Mail-Adresse *maximilian.mustermann@privat.* 
>   *musterstadt.com* erreichen oder telefonisch unter 0815/08150815.

Comment: +1 Prominente Hinweise darauf, dass man so etwas wann immer möglich vermeiden sollte.

Comment: monospace ist auch eine Lösung, s. meine Frage "Is monospacing URLs still advised in academic writing" (o. ä. Titel) im SE für Grafikdesign.

Answer (score 5):

Das Problem betrifft nicht nur E-Mail-Adressen sondern auch Web-Adressen. Diese sogar um so mehr, als sie ja natürlicherweise sehr lang werden können (Unterseite einer Unterseite einer Website).

In solchen Fällen, wenn Zeilenumbruch unumgänglich ist, empfiehlt sich in der Tat (wie von Björn Friedrich als 3. Möglichkeit schon dargelegt) einfach zu umbrechen, aber keinen Trennstrich zu setzen.

Etwa so:

> www.beispielsite.de/unterseite/unterseite/unter
>   seite/endlich-die-richtige-seite.html

So etwas kommt im Alltag natürlich selten vor. Es kann aber vorkommen in wissenschaftlichen Werken, wenn man Quellen in Fußnoten angibt, und diese Quellen sind sehr lange Internet-Adressen.

Nun merkt Kommentator IQV ganz richtig an, dass im obigen Beispiel eine Trennung an den Schrägstrichen natürlich näher läge. Da hat er recht. Allerdings gibt es auch solche Internetadressen:

> www.beispielsite.de/lsicnflk54-ckm9440ou9xcs-3klkjfdlkdf845904sldkdfjulsd
>   8dfldkjf893003mkdjflk45l5l7l.php

Und hier einen Trennstrich einzufügen, wäre eindeutig keine gute Idee.

Oder solche:

> www.beispielsite.de/fragen-und-antworten/kann-man-bei-e-mail-adressen-
>   am-zeilenende-eine-trennung-machen.php

Hier wird es nun ganz klar, dass ein Trennstrich, der nur der Trennung dient, nicht aber Teil der eigentlichen Web-Adresse ist, Verwirrung stiften würde.

Solche Adressen sind z.B. in Foren und News-Sites recht verbreitet. Siehe übrigens - es lebe die Selbstreferenz - die Adresse

> httbs://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40335/wie-trennt-man-eine-lange-
> e-mail-adresse-richtig/40342#40342

Comment: Wäre es in dem Fall nicht sinvoll(er), am slash "/" zu trennen?

Comment: @IQV  - Ja, da hast du recht. Das Beispiel ist in diesem Sinne ein bisschen blöd. Es gibt aber durchaus sehr lange Internetadressen - gerade die, die einen zufallsgenerierten String haben - ohne solche Schrägstriche. Ich ergänze ein entsprechendes Beispiel.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde allenfalls vor oder nach dem @ umbrechen, dann aber ohne Trennstrich – in allen anderen Varianten besteht die Gefahr, dass der Leser beim Abschreiben nicht weiß, ob der Trennstrich mit einzugeben ist oder nur auf die Silbentrennung zurückzuführen ist. 
Wo es um Visitenkarten geht, würde ich allen Ernstes die Beschaffung einer kürzeren Mailadresse erwägen – kein Mensch hat Lust, einen solchen Bandwurm abzutippen! 
Von einer diesbezüglichen Regel weiß ich nichts.

Answer (score 3):

Erst mal zur eigentlichen Frage: geregelt ist hier meines Wissens nichts.

Wie schon von vielen anderen geschrieben, ist auch meine erste Empfehlung: wenn irgend möglich vermeiden. Wenn das nicht geht, Du aber dafür auf typographische Gestaltungmöglichkeiten zurückgreifen kannst, würde ich ein Trennzeichen verwenden, das eindeutig als solches zu erkennen ist. Z.B. '↵' (Unicode #8629, HTML &crarr;), und zusätzlich in einer zurückgesetzten Schriftfarbe (z.B. grau statt schwarz). Sowas habe ich für Web-Adressen schon oft in IT-Zeitschriften gesehen. Für Mail-Adressen sollte das auch funktionieren. Am geeignetsten erscheint auch mir die Stelle vor oder hinter dem '@'.

Comment: In diesem Ausnahmefall würde ich vielleicht auch zum Gleichheitszeichen greifen, und das nach Möglichkeit an eine Stelle, die die Trennung deutlich macht, also ein Wort vorname.nachname1-nachname2@firmen = 
teil1-firmenteil2.de hinein. Farbliche Hervorhebung ist auch eine gute Idee.